# External USB-drive keeps powering on during mount operations

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, usb

I have an external hard drive connected to my machine running Fedora 33 (GNOME 3.38.5) over USB3.1. That drive usually goes to sleep after 5 minutes. Now each time I mount or umount another USB-drive, the system causes the external drive to power on and wait until it is up and running again. During that time the system is waiting and unresponsive, which is really an issue, especially since this process takes a few seconds and happens several times throughout a day. Does this happen, because the list of mounted drives is being updated? Is there a way to exclude that particular drive from whatever is happening here?

Has anyone experienced something similar? Could anyone explain why this keeps happening? I'd appreciate any help or if someone could point me into the right direction.